# Date format SMS

Tags: javascript, date, format, sms

I'm actually using an API (SendInBlue). This API send sms to my customer. Sometimes there is a date in my SMS.

I know smartphone can recognize a date and create a kind on link on this date to add a new meeting in the calendar.

Actually, my date format is : 11/10/2018 00H00 but smartphone does create this "link" to add it in the calendar.

Someone can give me some clues about the format to use ? 
Thank's

Comment: try the [iso standard](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) yyyy-mm-dd (2018-10-25)

Comment: Thank's for your help. Sadly it's doesn't work. I already tried a lot of standard format

Comment: Looking at the [SendInBlue documentation](https://apidocs.sendinblue.com/mailin-sms/#2), it expects dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss. Or are you asking what format the date should be in for the device to recognise it as a date? 11/10/2018 is ambiguous, I don't know if that's 11 October or 10 November. Something unambiguous like "Thu 11 Oct 2018 14:45" should be preferred and will likely be easily detected by mobile devices that can recognise dates.

Comment: Hi @RobG thank's for you recommandation. I will try this format.